# What is wrong with this python code?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to use recursion here but my code is wrong. Help me where I'm wrong. It is only return True. I have to return recursive statement as well as the condition in which the function return False. Basically, I want to expand my code.

```
def mypalindrome(l):
  if l==[] or len(l) == 1:
    return(True)
  else:
    return(mypalindrome(l[1:-1]))
```

Comment: Because there's no condition on which the function will return false. You have to add a `if` terminal condition to  return false.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have most of it right.  You just need to call the arguments properly and fix the return value.  Additionally, you are missing the check that checks the first and the last character, here's an example:

```
string = "reallear"

def mypalindrome(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
        return True
    elif string[0] == string[-1]:
        return mypalindrome(string[1:-1])
    else:
        return False

print mypalindrome(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to check word palindrome

```
def mypalindrome(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return True
    if l[0] != l[-1]:
        return False
    return mypalindrome(l[1:-1])
```

or more elegant way

```
def mypalindrome(l):
    return l == l[::-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def mypalindrome(l):
  if l==[] or len(l) == 1:
    return(True)
  else:
    return(mypalindrome(l[1:-1]) and l[0] == l[-1])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.